# How to differentiate Outlook folders to return visible folders only?

Tags: .net, outlook

I pull the Outlook (365, Exchange server) folders like this:

```
 Dim otkApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
 Dim otkNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace = otkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Dim folders = otkNameSpace.Folders
```

This gets me several additional folders along with those that I see in the Outlook app. For example, I get "Sync Issues", "Quick Step Settings" and "Conversation Action Settings".

How can I remove those folders?

I don't see any property that is different than those at "Inbox" folder. I remove only some of them with a check `.DefaultMessageClass = "IPM.Note"`.
[image: debug]

Edit (based on an Dmitry's answer):

```
Dim prop As Boolean = False

Try
    prop = subfolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B")
Catch ex As System.Exception
    prop = False
End Try

If prop Or Not subfolder.DefaultMessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    Continue For
End If
```

This gets rid of most of those folders, but "Sync Issues" remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the folders with `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` MAPI property  == true. The property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B"`) can be accessed using `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. You can see that property in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMAPIFolder button.

Comment: Thanks legend, it almost works, see my edit if you want...